# Android: Adding hooks for voice activation

Tags: android, voice-recognition

Is it possible to make an android app intercept voice activation commands?

For example, these work already

> **Listen to** [The Beatles]
>   **Call** [Pizza Hut]

I want to add one for

> **Remind me** [in 5 minutes to start cooking the fish]
>   **Remind me** [to email bob at 6PM]

And then parse the english myself to save the reminder.

Even better if I can exclude unexpected stuff like

> remind me lyrics

which is not a reminder request, but actually a google search request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a browser that accepts http requests to google.com. Read the url and if it is a call to the Google Search, check the search terms. If the search terms do not match one of the hooks, call the system default browser with the same URL.

If they do match, take appropriate action, and of course do not call Google Search.

Sort of a hackish way to get it to work, but it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

These are things that are included in the OS.  You could make an application yourself that could accomplish these things, but you likely aren't able to make changes to the built-in programs that are controller by your hardware buttons.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I hope this helps!